Sum $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n\sin(x^n),\quad x\in(-1,1)$
I am trying to find a closed-form expression for the sum
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n\sin(x^n),\quad x\in(-1,1)$$
Can anyone help me / provide any useful insights?
What I've Tried
I know a couple methods for evaluating trig sums (like De Moivre's thm.) but they didn't obviously apply. By rewriting the inside as a Taylor series and switching the order of summation, the sum can be rewritten.
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n\sin(x^n) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m}{(2m+1)!}\left(x^n\right)^{2m+2} $$
$$= \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m}{(2m+1)!} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(x^{2m+2}\right)^n$$
The inner sum is geometric
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n\sin(x^n) = \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m}{(2m+1)!} \frac{1}{1-x^{2m+2}}$$
$$=\frac{1}{1-x^2}-\frac{1}{3!\ (1-x^4)}+\ldots$$
This new sum converges much faster on the interval but it's not obvious how to sum it either.
The closest I've gotten is by plotting the function and noticing it looked similar to the plot of secant. By fitting a function of the form
$$\sin(1) \sec^b(a x)\rightarrow \sin(1) \sec^{0.9149}(1.5789 x)$$
it approximates the function quite closely but doesn't quite fit (which I should have expected as it was a total guess).

Is this an exercise from a book or class, or part of some other computation or theory? In particular, do you have reason to believe there is a closed form, or you're hoping to find one?

@aschepler I was just trying so solve it for fun. I am being a bit optimistic assuming there is a closed form solution.

You could try rewriting the sum of rational functions into an infinite product, see if there's any pattern in the numerator.

@ClaudeLeibovici Oops, yes

Many Lacunary type series, after using $\sin(z)’s$ complex form, do not have a closed form. It also may be interesting to find an integral representation.

Since
$$\int x^n\,\sin(x^n)\,dn=-\frac{\cos \left(x^n\right)}{\log (x)}$$ we can try the simplest form of Euler-MacLaurin summation which would give for $x>0$
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n\sin(x^n)=\frac 1 2 \sin(1)+\frac{\cos (1)-1}{\log (x)}-\frac{\sin (1)+\cos
   (1)}{12} \log (x) +$$ $$\frac{6 \cos (1)-5 \sin (1)}{720} \log ^3(x) +
\frac{74 \sin (1)+33 \cos (1)}{30240}\log ^5(x)+$$ $$\frac{57 \sin (1)-1309 \cos(1)}{1209600}\log ^7(x)$$ which seems to be decent.
For $x=\frac 12$ the result is $\color{red}{1.1638}18$
Edit
Genarating equally spaced values for $x=0.01$ up to $x=0.99$ by steps for $0.01$ and use as a very simplistic model
$$y=a-\frac b{\log(x)}-c\,\log(x)$$ for an adjusted $R^2=0.999993$, you have
$$\begin{array}{l|lll}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Std Error} & \text{Confidence Interval} \\
\hline
 a & 0.44125 & 0.00267 & \{0.43596,0.44654\} \\
 b & 0.45927 & 0.00014 & \{0.45898,0.45955\} \\
 c & 0.08489 & 0.00185 & \{0.08122,0.08855\} \\
\end{array}$$
and notice that
$$\frac 1 2 \sin(1)=0.42074 \quad\quad 1-\cos(1)=0.45970\quad\quad \frac{\sin (1)+\cos(1)}{12}=0.08329$$
